# Comparable seach box with Chrome tools similiar to Firebug/FirePath

Tags: firebug, firepath

Is there some comparable tool to the below screenshot in Chrome (screenshot below is firebug/firepath)  I liked how the user can place the string of the xpath in the search box and as the user types if something matches it would highlight.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chrome DevTools have integrated support for XPath searches within their inspector. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the search and start typing your XPath:

[image: XPath search in Chrome DevTools Inspector]

The Firefox DevTools do not provide this feature yet, though [there's a request for it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=963933).

Both tools allow to search for CSS selectors, though.